# Chrome extension - Not able to parse specific XPATH inside a dynamic table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to fetch the contents of the below url using XMLHttpRequest -

http://www.flipkart.com/d-link-dsl-2750u-wireless-n-adsl2-4-port-wi-fi-router/p/itmd4ky52tgtbawn?pid=RTRD4KY4UNGYCZFG&otracker=from-search&srno=t_1&query=D-Link-DSL-2730U-Wireless-N-150-ADSL2+-4-Port-Router-%28Black%29&ref=0ba9ca94-7beb-4f36-ae53-5c9fe29bf5b0

and trying to fetch one of the prices under the section called : Sold by 38 sellers. The XPATH for this price is 
//*[@id="fk-mainbody-id"]/div/div[8]/div/div/div[6]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]/div/div/div/span

However, since the table is constructed dynamically, I do not get the details of the table and this specific price using XMLHttpRequest. It seems that some javascript constructs this table when page loads in the browser. But in my case since I am using XMLHttpRequest, How to do that?

I have googled out, and many suggested using iFrame - I cannot use because the external websites I would load would be from different origins, and mostly they have X-Frame-Options' set to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

Comment: I just had a big smile on my face watching my browser's development console output when loading this page...

Comment: yeah, i know what you mean. did you get a chance to look at the issue by the way.